# Backbitting people and seeking forgivness without apologising to them and not feeling regret

Tags: forgiveness

Asalamu alaykum wa rahmatullah wa barakatuh
I remembered that I have backbitten my parents and sisters and I really know how wrong and how unfair it is, I want to repent but I can't tell them about it and apologies because I'm sure it will cause big problems and break their hearts and I don't want that, but the most important part of repentance is regret, and I use to feel regret from the depths of my heart but now I stopped feeling regret and the problem is that I repeated that sin, so do I have to re-new my repentance? And does backbiting your family and not feeling regret make the situation worse which may lead to that Allah will not forgive me unless I apologise to them? But I always make the best dua for them and I make them happy and I hell them and support them so would this + not getting back to this sin + regretting it alone be good enough without apologising? I really can't teLloyd them I was backbiting them please help
And is saying mean things in your head about someone considered backbiting?
And would you please tell me how to feel regret?
I'm so sorry for the trouble
May Allah bless all those who help me and make them as hapPygocentrus as they are going to make me feel and even more happy in this dunya and in the afterlife
Jasakumu Allah alf Khair

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Shaykhul-Islam Ibn Taymiyyah said: "*Whoever wrongs a person by slandering him, backbiting about him or insulting him, then repents, Allah will accept his repentance, but if the one who was wronged finds out about that, he has the right to settle the score. But if he slandered him or backbit about him and the person did not hear of that, then there are two views according to the scholars, both of which were narrated from Ahmad, the more correct of which is that he should not tell him that he spoke against him in his absence. It was said that he should rather speak well of him in his absence just as he spoke badly of him in his absence, as al-Hasan al-Basri said: the expiation for gheebah is to pray for forgiveness for the person about whom you backbite.*" Majmu’ al-Fatawa (3/291)

Here is a general Du‘a for this matter:

> Narrated from Abu Huraira:
> that he heard the Prophet (ﷺ) saying, "*O Allah! If I should ever abuse a believer, please let that be a means of bringing him near to You on the Day of Resurrection.* (اللَّهُمَّ فَأَيُّمَا مُؤْمِنٍ سَبَبْتُهُ فَاجْعَلْ ذَلِكَ لَهُ قُرْبَةً إِلَيْكَ يَوْمَ الْقِيَامَةِ)" In Al-Bukhari (6361)

Furthermore, since you can extract from the Fatwa, you should regret your sin (and know about the punishment of this sin), pray then for the Person‘s forgiveness, for him to receive Jannatul Firdaus from Allah and if you do that, then the Angel make Du‘a similar to what you have said when you supplicate for your brother.

> Allah's Messenger (ﷺ) said: "*There is no believing servant who supplicates for his brother behind his back (in his absence) that the Angels do not say: The same be for you too.*" In Muslim (2732a)